# How to interpret with each loop?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to interpret with `each` loop. but I am not able to come with a good solution( ember way! )

how to handle this scernario?

From the loop I am printing `16` digit. whenever the `index` reach `4 ( index % 4 == 0 )` I would like to add a hyphen.(-)

how to achive this?

here is my route.js :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Ember.Route.extend({
      model(){
        return [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];
      }
    });
```

my hbs file:

```
<h1>Each with condition </h1>
{{#each model as |num index |}}
    {{index}}
 {{/each}}
```

but I look like:

```
<h1>Each with condition </h1>
{{#each model as |num index |}}
    {{index}} {{ if index % 4 == 0 }} --  {{/if}}
 {{/each}}
```

So, what is the correct ember approach for this?

[Twiddle here](https://ember-twiddle.com/fc8b14b11990b84e19f414e3d66579bf?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write your own helper to achieve this. I updated [your twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/3d614fb2df992ce4a4620618d4755778?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

helpers/my-helper.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export function myHelper([index,position,totalLength]) {
  if(index === totalLength-1){
    return '';
  }
  index = index+1;
  return index%position === 0 ? " -- ":"";
}
export default Ember.Helper.helper(myHelper);
```

in application.hbs,

```
{{#each model as |num index |}}
    {{index}}{{my-helper index 4 model.length}}
 {{/each}}
```

Comment: got. very thanks to you. But still the last hypen after the 16th digit not required, how to remove that?

Comment: You need to pass totalLength too to identify. I just updated my answer..

Comment: There is [composable helper addon](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#slice), where there are lots of predefined helpers are available you can use slice helper too.